# VLC plugin in android browser

Tags: browser, video, video-streaming, vlc

i found VLC for Android Beta (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon&hl=sk) which enables to play videos in VLC player on Android. But I need VLC plugin for browser on Android (for default browser or for chrome or any other browser). Is it possible ? Can you suggest mi anything ? When I installed VLC for Android Beta it not contains web plugin...

btw, I am using android 4.1.1.

Comment: What site are you trying to play a video on? Usually they use Flash.

Comment: I have video saved on my server - and want to play it in vlc plugin in browser

Comment: How aboout if you just download the video, and play it locally using VLC media player? Otherwise, I think you'd have to create/implement a website that streams the video. At other times, the browser will ask you to open / stream the file using a 3rd-party player.

Comment: I have to stream it in browser - on windows it works fine with vlc plugin and video starts playing